# Background image (pattern) after heading using CSS only

Tags: html, css

Is this possible to create following effect using CSS. I only have a H2 element in HTML, and i do not have any control on HTML of the page. I can only change CSS.

I tried it with :before and :after but no success so far.

[image]

This will be used in a CMS, so i can not be sure how or where end user will be adding headings.

Comment: can you post the container of this h2 tag ?

Comment: I do not have any container that i can use for this effect, container in my page is a div that wraps around whole content area.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best shot would be (since you cannot edit any of the HTML and you want a CSS only solution) to play a little with the position and z-index of the container and the h2:after pseudo element:

**HTML**:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <h2 class="heading">New Collection </h2>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
#wrapper {
    width:100%;
    height:800px;
    background:green;
    position:relative;
    z-index:-2;
}
.heading {
    display:inline;
    background:green;
}
.heading:after {
    content:'';
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
    height:20px;
    background:#d3d3d3;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

Check this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/KarimAG/fEs5j/)**, I know it's not that fancy, but I think you cannot do more than that using CSS only.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is pretty close, but it will work only if i have heading at the top of the content area, not when heading is in between somewhere in content.

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way that I know of is to put a span inside of the H2, but still around the inner text, then apply one style to the span and one style to the H2.

**EDIT:** You can use a little bit of jQuery to add the span inside your H2 tags.

HTML:

```
<h2><span>New Collection</span></h2>
```

CSS:

```
h2 {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 16px;
    background: #eee;
    color: #999;
}
h2 span {
    padding-right: 10px;
    background: #fff;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('h2').each(function() {
        var title = $(this).html();
        $(this).html('<span>' + title + '</span>');
    });
});
```

**Here's a [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/y825e/2/)**

Comment: Thanks, but as i mentioned i do not have any control on HTML, i can not add span in H2.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that! You can add a little jQuery to put the spans in there, but if that's not a viable option, let me know.